# Can prime attributes depend on each other?

Tags: database, primary-key, normalization, composite-key

I have a relation R{id, building, floor, sequence, capacity} where:

```
(building,floor,sequence) -> id 
id -> (building,floor,sequence)
(building,floor,sequence) -> capacity
id -> capacity
```

It seems that this doesn't violate any normal form. However, is it really ok for id to depend on (building,floor,sequence) and vice versa even though id is the primary key?
If no, what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any relation with multiple candidate keys, there'll inevitably be cyclic dependencies between them - since any candidate key can uniquely identify each tuple and each tuple has a value for each candidate key.

The fact that one key is selected as being "more equal" than the others and named as the primary key is irrelevant. (When we're talking abstractly, as here. Certain database products may have features which do indeed make the primary key "more equal" than the alternate keys)